# Stop text input with 100% width and 10px padding extending beyond 100% width

Tags: css

I am styling a text input with 100% width and 10px padding like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Outer element
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
        <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search here...">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="GO">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

#s {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#searchsubmit {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem is the text input extends beyond the width of the wrapper. [See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN6cR/).

I've tried adding "box-sizing: border-box" and -moz-box-sizing: border-box" but I'm still seeing the input extending beyond 100% on certain browsers e.g. Android.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `box-sizing`:

```
#s {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN6cR/1/)

Note: It's supported by all major browsers since IE8. For Android just don't forget the `-webkit` prefix. [More Details](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

Answer (score 0):

Remove left and right `padding`. If you need `padding`, play with `width`.

```
#s 
{
    width: 99%;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```